# Code print on browser (Firefox) after implementing the java filter

Tags: java, html

I am using code to make user login form. The issue is I am able to login from Internet Explorer but when I login from Firefox this same code prints the HTML version of the code on the screen. I am using java filter.

Below code is being printed on the screen.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><!DOCTYPE html  "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd"><html>
    <head>
<meta HTTP_EQUIV="pragma" content="no-cache"/>
<meta HTTP_EQUIV="cache-control" content="no-cache" />
<meta HTTP_EQUIV="cache-control" content="no-store"/>
<meta HTTP_EQUIV="expires" content="0" />
<title>ABC</title>
<script language="javascript" > 
 if(window.parent.length > 0) {
         var url = "/java/ehr.Home";
         var par = "null";
         if(par != "" && par != "null") { 
                 url = url + "?" + par ;
         }
         if(url != "") { 
                 window.parent.location = url; 
         }
 }
</script>
</head>
<frameset rows="111,*"  framespacing="0" frameborder="0" border="0">
<frame name="top" src="ehr.cms.PageBuilder?Page=topNavigationLegacy:/manager/home.xml" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" scrolling="no" noresize="">
<frame name="middle" src="ShowLoading?LanguageCode=en&msgid=IDL_LOADING&redirect=/java/ehr.cms.PageBuilder?Page=topNavigationLegacy:/manager/home.xml" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" scrolling="auto" noresize="" />
<frame name="middle" src="ehr.cms.PageBuilder?Page=/manager/home.xml" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" scrolling="auto" noresize="">
<noframes>
<body>
<p>Please use a browser which is able to show FRAMESETS!</p>
</body>
</noframes>
</frameset>
</html>
```

I also set the content-type "text/html" in java filter but getting the same problem. Can anyone look into my problem.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your web server is delivering the HTTP response with the incorrect content type.   You can confirm this by looking at the browser's Page Info page: use the "Tools > Page Info" menu entry, or CTRL-I.  I expect that it will show that Firefox thinks that the page type is something like "text/plain".

In the "Tools" menu you should find other tools that will allow you to see what the response actually contains; i.e. what the "content-type" header contains.

I imagine that the reason that IE renders the page is that it is simply being more forgiving of what is basically an incorrect HTTP response from your server.

---

> I also set the content-type "text/html" in java filter but getting the same problem.

Apparently, that is not working properly.  (Perhaps you are not doing it right?)  Checking the actual response headers at the browser end should help you validate this.